# angular add empty mat-option to all not required mat-select in my app

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can I add dynamically empty `mat-option` to all not required `mat-select` in my app.

like :

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
         <mat-label>HMO</mat-label>
         <mat-select>
              <--how can I add this dynamically-->
              <mat-option>--</mat-option>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let hmo of HMOList"
                              [value]="hmo.Code">
                    {{ hmo.Desc }}
              </mat-option>
         </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

any idea?

Comment: Would that work? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpvjf2-t3huhn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the response from Prince, but my model didn't update. And I added the following in OptionalMatSelectDirective

```
import { Directive, HostListener, OnInit, Renderer2, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSelect } from '@angular/material/select';

@Directive({
  selector: 'mat-select'
})
export class OptionalMatSelectDirective {

  constructor(private matSelect: MatSelect, private elementRef: ElementRef,
              private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  @HostListener('openedChange', ['$event'])
  onOpenedChange( isOpened : boolean)
  {

    if(!isOpened || this.matSelect.required)
    {
      return;
    }
    const matOption = this.renderer.createElement('mat-option');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(matOption, 'class', 'mat-option');
    this.renderer.listen(matOption,'click', ()=>
    {
      this.matSelect.value = '';
      **this.matSelect.ngControl.viewToModelUpdate(undefined);**
      this.matSelect.close();
    });

    const panel= document.querySelector('.mat-select-panel');
    if(!panel)
    {
      throw new Error('Cannot find mat select panel');
    }
    this.renderer.insertBefore(panel,matOption, panel.firstChild);


  }
}
```

And, it worked for me!

Comment: Nice! i added the follow row in order to activate also the selectionChange event: this.matSelect.selectionChange.emit(new MatSelectChange(this.matSelect, undefined)); You can see the complete example at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpvjf2-eearb9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-overview-example.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpvjf2-t3huhn), based on the various answers here.

The directive below is applied to `mat-select`, so you do not have to add any extra attributes. It uses the `required` attribute on the select to know whether to add any blank option when the dropdown opens.

**Note**: You cannot easily add items to the underlying list of mat options used by the `mat-select` component, so the mat options elements are added manually, and events need to be bound manually too (I did it for the `click` event);

```
import { Directive, HostListener, OnInit, Renderer2, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSelect } from '@angular/material/select';

import { Directive, HostListener, OnInit, Renderer2, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSelect } from '@angular/material/select';

@Directive({
  selector: 'mat-select'
})
export class OptionalMatSelectDirective {

  constructor(private matSelect: MatSelect, private elementRef: ElementRef,
  private renderer: Renderer2) { }

    @HostListener('openedChange', ['$event'])
    onOpenedChange( isOpened : boolean) 
    {

      if(!isOpened || this.matSelect.required)
      {
        return; //Closing panel, or select is required
      }
      //Manually create a mat option DOM element
      let matOption = this.renderer.createElement("mat-option");
      this.renderer.setAttribute(matOption, 'class', 'mat-option');

      //Bind events to the new mat option
      this.renderer.listen(matOption,'click', ()=>
      {
        this.matSelect.value = "";
        this.matSelect.close();
      });

      //Try to add the new mat option in first position of the list
      let panel= document.querySelector('.mat-select-panel');
      if(!panel)
      {
        throw "Cannot find mat select panel";
      }
      this.renderer.insertBefore(panel,matOption, panel.firstChild);


  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very nice, but still missing here, the model is not updated accordingly, (In addition there was no activation of selection change event I added ...) this example showing the problem of the model https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpvjf2-ka7mw5?file=src%2Fapp%2Foptional-mat-select.directive.ts

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just modify `HMOList` behind the scene like `HMOList = [ ...HMOList, { code: 'None', Desc: ''} ]` (or other way around as You want the default option first)? It seems a little bit hacky but it is also seems to be the easiest one. Or better store additional array for `mat-select` if we want to keep the original array as we copy everything over either way to make sure UI and whatever else will be updated.

Comment: Thanks, but this solution will required handling in every mat-select, I search single implementation that will effects on all select`s in the system (like directive)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this task,

**First approach**
first is you can create a property in component class and control the visibility of default mat-option. And bind this property in template like below:

Template

```
  <mat-select [required]="isRequired">
    <mat-option *ngIf="isRequired">---</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

Component class

```
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  isRequired = true;
  foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];
}
```

Please use the following working link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-azkmrp

**Second approach**
Second approach is you can use template reference variable in template only and use it to add default mat-option.
Here I have created a #matselect template reference variable and added the required attribute. Using this template reference variable with the default mat-option. Just toggle the required attribute to test.

```
 <mat-select #matselect required>
    <mat-option *ngIf="matselect.required">---</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

Please find working code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpvjf2

Comment: Thanks, but your answer mean that I create custom control and I search single implementation that not required html structure change and will effects on all select`s in the system (like directive)

Comment: I think the second solution is the optimal solution for your problem. Even if you create a custom structural directive, still you need to create empty mat option in your template and you have to pass a variable saying when to show or not like i have done in second solution

Comment: Updated my second answer (stackblitz) where i have created a directive. Still you need to pass some information to directive to tell when to show

Comment: Thanks, but I have a big system with multiple components and pages that development by a lot of programmers
i search a creative and infrastructure solution in order to ensure that all select`s contains also empty value
Without trusting the writer to remember to add 
creation of custom elements not fix me the an written code 
i try implement myself directive on mat-select (and etc) selector
this directive auto add the wanted element to mat-select
But I couldn't exercise easily 
i think its the right direction
but ask help with the really implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript unshift function to add first value for all required select elements.

```
HMOList.unshift( {code:'', desc:'--'});
```

If you want to add same kind of option in every select box. I have made changes in stackblitz.

See [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-azkmrp-xzeldh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-default-option.directive.ts)

Comment: Thanks, but this solution will required handling in every mat-select, I search single implementation that will effects on all select`s in the system (like directive)

Comment: You can create a directive and pass your option list as input, that can solve the problem.

Comment: Added directive

Comment: Thanks, nice, but I was looking for a solution that works without adding an attribute in html

Comment: @StackOverflow How do you expect to add a directive without adding an attribute?

Comment: @David that is possible but not able to think the right way to push a new option at run time.

Comment: By adding a directive on mat-select selector

Comment: @StackOverflow You can create a directive on `mat-select`, but from that directive I don't think you will not be able to access the list, since the list is created with a `ngFor` and not bound to `mat-select` itself

Comment: What I was trying to do was implement a directive that would add a blank mat-option to the drop-down panel at the time of its opening, by Render to document, the problem was that the value was not exactly the same as the previous values and behaved differently. like : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpvjf2-hunspt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fempty-item.directive.ts

Comment: I have updated a little, re-positioned and added a function which will print on console. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpvjf2-jylm6o?file=src%2Fapp%2Fempty-item.directive.ts

Answer (score 0):

I can get you this far:

- Create a new directive with selector as `mat-select`
- Get a reference to the MatSelect element via `ContentChildren`
- I could use this to add an option to the `_results` array on the `MatSelect` but it doesn't update the DOM, so you need to figure that one out

This does not require any change to HTML.

Below is as far as I could get in a short amount of time. There will be a better way to add an option to the `MatSelect` - you basically need to look at the Angular source files and see how they add a MatOption and then replicate this in your Directive.

Good luck!

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'mat-select',
  exportAs: 'myMatSelect'
})
export class MyMatSelectDirective {

  constructor(
    public changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) { }

  select: MatSelect;

  @ContentChildren(MatSelect) set list(select: QueryList<MatSelect>) {
    this.select = select.first;

    // One possible option is to subscribe to the openChange event
    this.select.openedChange.subscribe(open => {
      let opt = document.createElement("mat-option");
      opt.innerHTML = "--";
      (<any>this.select.options)._results.unshift(new MatOption(new ElementRef(opt), this.changeDetectorRef, this.select, null));
      console.log(this.select)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not work for me, maybe can you add an example?