# is it possible to apply an angular directive on a component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, custom-component

I'm using Angular 9 and I've created a directive that append option elements to a DOM select

```
<select populateData></select>
```

This is the code for the directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[populateData]'
})
export class PopulateDataDirective {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private control: NgControl,
        private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        private vcr: ViewContainerRef,
        private periodoService: PeriodoService) {

        this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data => {
            data.forEach(x => {
                this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML += '<option value="'+x.id+'">'+
                    x.text+'</option>';
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Ok, perhaps adding option elements by manipulating DOM is not the best idea but I could find another way, so I'm migrating to nebular components and I don't want to create a custom component to encapsulate nb-select, instead I'd prefer to modify the directive and apply it on the nb-select component, something like this:

```
<nb-select populateData></nb-select>
```

But it's not working, it seems Angular ignores the directive for components, is there any method to achieve this?

Comment: why are you creating directive for options? If you wanna make it dynamic create a select component and pass data dynamically.

Comment: You can create a component which loops using ngfor to create the desired options.

Comment: Directives obviously do work on components. And this is a weird non-Angular way of building a dropdown. What is your ultimate goal here? Whatever it is, there must be a better way to achieve it.

Comment: It is definitely possible to apply a directive to a component. But in your scenario, this is likely to create other problems . See a similar question for mat-select dropdowns here https://stackoverflow.com/q/60949388/1160794